# Can't solve why error keeps popping up C# Process.Start

Tags: c#, .net

Basically I want another exe to launch when I press the button. It is a console app I made C# too. When I press the button it does not want to launch the exe and shows a error:

"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'"

I also have the folder inside the folder which is called "execprg". The code I am using is:

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Button5 Click:
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:/execprg/ProgramToLaunch.exe");

        }
```

If you can help thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means your exe location is incorrect

1. Check your exe location again
2. Change forward slash to backward slash. Windows prefers backward slash for paths

> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\execprg\ProgramToLaunch.exe");

Comment: Forward slashes don't matter, just tested that. The exe is in the wrong location.

Comment: I know it dosen't matter. That's why I mentioned "Windows prefer". It's optional but recommended

Comment: Exactly. It works with both. But Windows likes back slashes more (for directories or paths). It's always good to use in Win32 environments

Comment: I double checked the location and it is right. It keeps sending the same error

Comment: Can you check if your console app has access to this location? Since it is in subfolders inside the C:\ drive there might be a permission issue reaching it (*if you cross verified location path and spelling)

Comment: Never mind I got it to work. Sangeeth nandakumar's answer was right about "Windows prefers backward slash for paths". The only problem was to remove "c:" and leave it at "execprg/ProgramToLaunch.exe".